# Why Swift calls function not from an extension generic where clause?

Tags: swift, xcode, generics

If I call function (e.g funcB) from a class that have extension where clause directly all works as expected.

But if I call some another function (e.g funcA) of a class and called function use funcB inside I see a result from original funcB not from extension.

Code sample:

```
class Bar {

}

class Foo<T> {

    func funcA() {
        funcB()
    }

    func funcB() {
        print("Parent without clause")
    }

}

extension Foo where T: Bar {

    func funcB() {
        print("Parent + clause")
    }

}

Foo<Any>().funcB()

Foo<Bar>().funcB()

print("--")

Foo<Any>().funcA()

Foo<Bar>().funcA()
```

Output:

> Parent without clause
>
> Parent + clause
>
> --
>
> Parent without clause
>
> Parent without clause

I want to call different implementation depending on parent of T and send T to a second class.

If T is child of Bar, use Class<T: Bar> else return nil.

Comment: Well, just because one can extend type anywhere (even in different module, assuming `open` type) designing the system to make `funcA` to check all the extensions for proper `funcB` implementation would be nightmare.

Comment: @user28434 Ok, I want something like 
       if let t = T.self as? BaseModel.Type {
            return Parser<t>()
       }

But I receive "Use of undeclared type 't' " error.

Comment: `let t` exists in runtime, `Parser<t>` exists only during compilation. Those two will never meet.

Comment: @user28434 I understand, I wrote comment only for show an idea about what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have some kind of "abstract" class behavior, you can use a protocol instead of generic class.

Something like this:

```
class Bar: FooProtocol {
}

class Foo: FooProtocol {
}

protocol FooProtocol {
    func funcA()
    func funcB()
}

extension FooProtocol {
    func funcA() {
        funcB()
    }

    func funcB() {
        print("Parent without clause")
    }
}

extension FooProtocol where Self: Bar {
    func funcB() {
        print("Parent + clause")
    }
}
```

Here I have used a default implementation for the `FooProtocol` but you can define the functions int the `Foo` class and `Bar` class depending on what you want. 
Then you will have this result:

```
    let bar = Bar()
    bar.funcA() // Parent + clause
    bar.funcB() // Parent + clause

    let foo = Foo()
    foo.funcA() // Parent without clause
    foo.funcB() // Parent without clause
```

Comment: I need to call different functions depending on T class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct behaviour for current Swift implementation.

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10549